# C stdio redirection to and from child process

Tags: c, linux, io-redirection, stdio

I have a CLI program which read command lines from stdin and write the output to stdout. From what I understand, when I launch this program from a terminal, it become a child process of that terminal thus inherit the stdin and stdout.

Instead of launching the CLI from a terminal I want another program to launch it. I would like the CLI to take it's input from this program stdout and redirect it's output to this program stdin.

```
Terminal Program CLI
stdin -> stdin <-stdout
stdout<- stdout->stdin
```

I'm not sure but I think that I could just do :

```
system("</dev/stdout ./CLI >/dev/stdin &");
```

Is there a better way to do this, I feel like there is. I could create named pipe instead of using stdin and stdout.

Comment: You need to create pipes and connect the child process's stdin and stdout to the pipes. Then your program writes to the stdin pipe and reads from the stdout pipe.

Comment: You can't read from `/dev/stdout`, because it's only open for output. Vice versa for `/dev/stdin`.

Comment: Note that you're very likely to get into a deadlock because of buffering.

Answer (score 4):

You need [`pipe(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html):

> `pipe()` creates a pipe, a unidirectional data channel that can be
> used for interprocess communication.  The array `pipefd` is used to
> return two file descriptors referring to the ends of the pipe.
> `pipefd[0]` refers to the read end of the pipe.  `pipefd[1]` refers
> to the write end of the pipe.  Data written to the write end of
> the pipe is buffered by the kernel until it is read from the read
> end of the pipe.  For further details, see [`pipe(7)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html).

And you need [`dup2(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup.2.html):

```
int dup2(int oldfd, int newfd);
```

> The `dup2()` system call performs the same task as `dup()`, but
> instead of using the lowest-numbered unused file descriptor, it
> uses the file descriptor number specified in `newfd`.  In other
> words, the file descriptor `newfd` is adjusted so that it now
> refers to the same open file description as `oldfd`.
>
> If the file descriptor `newfd` was previously open, it is closed
> before being reused; the close is performed silently (i.e., any
> errors during the close are not reported by `dup2()`).

So, what you need are *two* pipes. Since one pipe can only do one direction, and you want full-duplex, you need two. Bellow are two very simple examples. `cap.c` is a program that reads one character and echoes it back upper-case. It does so indefinitely.

`pipe.c` is the program that will spawn `cap.c`, create both pipes, write to it, read back the child's response, and give us the response through `stderr` ( because we will have [`dup2(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup.2.html)ed the other, `stdin` and `stdout`). Code's commented.

```
/* cap.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    char buf;
    while(1) {
        read(0, &buf, 1);
        buf = toupper(buf);
        write(1, &buf, 1);
    }
}
```

And the other one...

```
/* pipe.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>

int main(void)
{
    int parent_write[2], child_write[2], ws;
    char *cap[2] = {"./cap", NULL}, buf;
    pid_t cpid;

    pipe(parent_write);
    pipe(child_write);

    /* pipe[0] -> read (you read from it)
     * pipe[1] -> write (you write to it)
     *
     * parent_write[0] -> the child will read this
     * parent_write[1] -> the parent writes here
     *
     * child_write[0] -> the parent reads here
     * child_write[1] -> the child writes here
     */

    if(!(cpid = fork())) {
        /* child process, the "add" */

        /* close the read end of child_write
         * close the write end of parent_write
         */
        close(child_write[0]);
        close(parent_write[1]);

        /* dup2 will swap our stdin(0) and stdout(1)
         * for the pipe 
         *
         * parent_write[0] -> our new stdin(0)
         * child_write[1] -> our new stdout(1)
         */
        dup2(parent_write[0], 0);
        dup2(child_write[1], 1);

        execv(*cap, cap);

    } else {
        /* close the read end parent_write
         * close the write end of child_write
         */
        close(parent_write[0]);
        close(child_write[1]);

        /* dup2 will swap...
         *
         * parent_write[1] -> new stdout
         * child_write[0] -> new stdin
         */
        dup2(parent_write[1], 1);
        dup2(child_write[0], 0);

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            buf = 'a' + i;
            write(1, &buf, 1);
            fprintf(stderr, "sent: %c\n", buf);
            read(0, &buf, 1);
            fprintf(stderr, "got : %c\n", buf);
        }
            
        kill(cpid, 1);
        wait(&ws);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And then...

```
$ gcc cap.c -o cap
$ gcc pipe.c -o pipe
$ ./pipe
sent: a
got : A
sent: b
got : B
sent: c
got : C
sent: d
got : D
sent: e
got : E
sent: f
got : F
sent: g
got : G
sent: h
got : H
sent: i
got : I
sent: j
got : J
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, in a terminal, you run some kind of shell like bash, ksh or tcsh. This shell is usually the child process of a terminal program like xterm or Konsole. Whenever you start a program in the terminal, that program will become the child process of the shell, something like this:

xterm -> bash -> my_cli_program

There is a command called pstree which shows a tree of processes with childs.

There is a function calle popen() which allows you to run a program much like system() but it allows you to write to that programs stdin *or* read from its stdout. Unfortunately you can only read or write with popen as a unidirectional pipe is used.

To both read and write to stdin and from stdout of your child process you will need two pipes created with pipe(). Once your pipes are created you can fork() and then use dup2() in both child and parent to connect stdout and stdin of your processes with the pipes that you created. Once everything is connected you can call system() or better execve() in the child process as system() would create yet another process.