# How to launch a program and have a pipe to both stdin and stdout in C on linux

Tags: c, process, pipe, stdout, stdin

I'm trying to write a C program to configure lemonbar, a status-bar for linux, and i'd like to have the bar be interactive.
The problem is that to write to the bar you have to use the program stdin and to know when an interactive element element is pressed lemonbar writes to it's own stdout.

I tried launching the program twice with `popen()` once in read mode and once in write mode, but it seems to cause conflicts and only one of the two pipes works at a time.

Is it possible to have both the stdin and stdout of a program at the same time?

Comment: Note that your question is _not_ about lemonbar. You specifically ask about "both the stdin and stdout of a program at the same time., it's an XY question.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68583996/c-stdio-redirection-to-and-from-child-process answer your question?

Comment: @KamilCuk yeah that answers it, if you want to make a reply with the link i'll close the question marking it as the solution